# Attaching arbitrary attributes to a Blade x component, binding attributes à la Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I created a component (using the [Material Components Web](https://material.io/develop/web/) libary).

I have 2 needs that I could not resolve using the Laravel Blade X components.

**To be able to add arbitrary, non previsible attributes to my components**

Let's say I use the `<x-mdc.top-app-bar />` component in my `index.blade.php` view:

```php
{{-- resources/views/index.blade.php --}}
<x-mdc.top-app-bar>
  <x-slot name="start">
    <x-mdc.top-app-bar-navigation />
    <x-mdc.top-app-bar-title>{{ config("app.name") }}</x-mdc.top-app-bar-title>
  </x-slot>
</x-mdc-top-app-bar>
```

The component is created like this:

```php
{{-- resources/views/components/mdc/top-app-bar.blade.php --}}
<header class="top-app-bar">
  @isset($start)
    <section class="top-app-bar__section--start">{{ $start }}</section>
  @endisset
  @isset($end)
    <section class="top-app-bar__section--end">{{ $end  }}</section>
  @endisset
</header>
```

So as you can see, I did not plan to support any `id` attribute. But as a consumer of the component, I'd like to add one. Maybe in the future I'd also like to add some `data-x` attributes...

So my first question: Is there any way to add a, potentially infinite number of, attributes when consuming a Blade x component?

**To be able to specify where the arbitrary attributes are located in the component**

As I thought about this issue, I remember Vue.js solved this using what they call "binded attributes" (and methods). So in Vue.js, even if the component would not predict some attribute, not only you can add a number of arbitrary attributes, but you can also redirect these attribute into a nested level of your component. For example, for a similar component consumed in a view in Vue.js:

```html
<!-- src/js/page/Home.vue -->
<template>
  <mdc-top-app-bar id="some-id">
    <!-- ... -->
  </mdc-top-app-bar>
</template>
<script>
import { MdcTopAppBar } from "../component";

export default {
  components: {
    MdcTopAppBar
  }
}
</script>
```

You would say that you want the attributes to be nested in a certain level:

```html
<!-- src/js/component/MdcTopAppBar.vue -->
<template>
  <header class="mdc-top-app-bar">
    <div v-bind="$attrs"> <!-- <---------------- BINDING HERE, nested level style -->
      <!-- ... -->
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

And my second question is: could we do this with Blade X components as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blade's tag attributes:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#managing-attributes

```
// Usage:
<x-alert type="error" :message="$message" class="mt-4"/>

// In component:
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'alert alert-'.$type]) }}>
    {{ $message }}
</div>
```